# Visual Studio build error "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms"

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, fips

I am trying to build my visual studio project and I get the following error for my XAML files:

This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms

I have searched online and changed the

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy

registry key to disabled. But I still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935434/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue this way:

1. remove the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy key(folder)
2. reboot
3. set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy to 0
4. set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy to 0
5. set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ControlSet002\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy to 0
6. reboot